# Substrings in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, substring

I'm relatively new to Oracle SQL and I am wondering if anyone is able to help me out.

I am attempting to return the first 50 rows from the `History` column of my `Employee` table. I am trying to return the instances where 'desk' is located in `history` after the first use of 'on'.

Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(History, INSTR(History, ' on ') + 3) AS subject
FROM Employee
WHERE subject LIKE '%desk%'
AND ROWNUM <= 50;
```

Comment: Add some sample records and expected result to avoid confusion. cover all scenarios that you can think of and what you expect to see as result in all such cases.

Comment: Rows from a column? One column for the history? That sounds like a very bad database design. I'd rather expect a table employee_history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For such more complicated like conditions, you can use `REGEXP_LIKE` which uses regular expressions:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(History, INSTR(History, ' on ') + 3) AS subject
  FROM Employee
 WHERE subject LIKE '%desk%'
   AND REGEXP_LIKE(History, '.*\son\s.*desk.*')
   AND ROWNUM <= 50
```

The final regular expression you have to use might be different to this one, but it should give you a start. I am pretty sure that your request is solvable in this way...

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(History, INSTR(History, ' on ') + 3) AS subject
FROM Employee
WHERE subject LIKE '%on%desk%' AND ROWNUM <= 50;
```

I think `LIKE` is preferred to regular expressions just because it should be a bit faster.